# Calendar showing null when date begins in previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

This is the syntax I am using to create my calendar.  The issue that I have is that since the startdate of Week1 is in 2012, startdate is showing as null.  Is there a way to have the startdate (or enddate in other instances) populate even when it is in a different year? @Winds Of Change ---
That adds in a start date and end date where previously it was null.  But what I am after is for example, I need my date range to run Sat - Wed.  So let's take week 53 for 2013.  The date range should be 12/28/2013 -- 01/01/14.  Is there a way to tinker the calander into displaying in that format?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar (
    CalendarYear INT NOT NULL,
    CalendarWeek INT NOT NULL,
    WeekStartDate VARCHAR(50),
    WeekEndDate VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Calendar PRIMARY KEY (
        CalendarYear,
        CalendarWeek
        )
    )

SET DATEFIRST 6

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
    @NumOfDays INT

SET @StartDate = '20130101'
SET @NumOfDays = 1000;

WITH calendar
AS (
    SELECT TOP (@NumOfDays) dateadd(day, row_number() OVER (
                ORDER BY sc1.column_id
                ) - 1, @StartDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM sys.columns sc1
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns sc2
    )
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (
    CalendarYear,
    CalendarWeek,
    WeekStartDate,
    WeekEndDate
    )
SELECT DATEPART(year, c.CalendarDate) AS Year,
    convert(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(week, c.CalendarDate)) AS Week, --DATEPART(week, c.CalendarDate) AS Week,    
    MAX(CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, c.CalendarDate)
            WHEN 1
                THEN convert(VARCHAR(50), c.CalendarDate, 101)
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS StartDate,
    MAX(CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, c.CalendarDate)
            WHEN 7
                THEN convert(VARCHAR(50), c.CalendarDate, 101)
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS EndDate
FROM calendar c
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, c.CalendarDate),
    DATEPART(Week, c.CalendarDate)
ORDER BY Year,
    startdate,
    convert(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(week, c.CalendarDate)) --Week

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Calendar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is is that you're grouping by week and year, but at the beginning/end of the year, the year begins/ends on a different week.  So if the first week starts on Wednesday, it's only a 3 day week for that Year.

I've had a small tinker, and I've got it working so that it displays the first/last day of the year as the start/end date of the week, by changing things around.  Here is my modified version:

```
SELECT
   DATEPART(year, c.CalendarDate) AS Year,
   convert(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(week, c.CalendarDate)) AS Week, --DATEPART(week, c.CalendarDate) AS Week,    
   convert(VARCHAR(50), MIN(c.CalendarDate), 101) AS StartDate,
   convert(VARCHAR(50), MAX(c.CalendarDate), 101) AS EndDate
FROM 
   calendar c
GROUP BY 
   DATEPART(year, c.CalendarDate),
   DATEPART(Week, c.CalendarDate)
ORDER BY 
   Year,
   startdate,
   convert(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(week, c.CalendarDate)) --Week
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** In response to your comment/edit, have a look at these update statements.  Put them after your insert.

**EDIT2:** Don't use the above insert as well as the updates.

```
update dbo.Calendar set WeekStartDate = convert(VARCHAR(50), dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(week, -1, cast(WeekEndDate as datetime))), 101)
where WeekStartdate is null

update dbo.Calendar set WeekEndDate = convert(VARCHAR(50), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(week, 1, WeekStartDate)), 101)
where WeekEndDate is null
```

Comment: That adds in a start date and end date where previously it was null.  But what I am after is for example, I need my date range to run Sat - Wed.  So let's take week 53 for 2013.  The date range should be 12/28/2013 -- 01/01/14.  Is there a way to tinker the calander into displaying in that format?
(original post modified with same addition)

Comment: Please review my latest changes to see if they help.

Comment: This is the output that I get
2013 53 12/28/2013 12/31/2013
2014 1 01/01/2014 01/03/2014

Could I have this combined and EITHER show week 53 is 12/28/2013 - 01/03/2014 OR Week 1 Runs 12/28/2013 - 01/03/2014?

Comment: It doesn't seem you're adding my update at the end.  Please check the update statements I've added in my Edit.  They should be put in after the insert.  To clarify, the insert should be reverted back to your previous version, this is instead of my previous insert change.